# ¿Cómo añado un rango de datos a un array en Bash?

Tags: array, bash

Creo un array de rangos e imprimo su cantidad de elementos:

```
arrayRanks=({A..D} {1..4})
echo "El array tiene ${#arrayRanks[*]} elementos"
```

Puedo agregar un elemento al final del array a la vez que actualizo su cantidad de elementos:

```
arrayRanks[${#arrayRanks[*]}]=33
echo "El array ahora tiene ${#arrayRanks[*]} elementos"
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, pero si quiero agregar un rango o un conjunto de elementos mediante un rango al final del array o al inicio, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene definir manualmente el tamaño de un array, si `${#arrayRanks[*]}` ya te lo da? Lo suyo sería siempre trabajar con exactamente ese valor, no con una "foto" puntual de su valor.

Comment: Gracias ya edite, pero... ¿Sabes si lo de los rangos es posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás añadiendo un rango usando la expresión `bla=(cosas)` y funciona perfectamente.

Para añadir más elementos a un array debes usar `bla+=(más cosas)`. Fíjate en que es exactamente la misma expresión, pero con `+=`:

```
$ arrayRanks=({A..B} {1..3})
$ printf "%s\n" "${arrayRanks[@]}" 
A
B
1
2
3
$ arrayRanks+=({M..N} {99..101})    # añadimos más valores con +=
$ printf "%s\n" "${arrayRanks[@]}" 
A
B
1
2
3
M
N
99
100
101
```

Para añadir datos al principio, se me ocurre redefinir el array usando `array=(nuevos elementos "${arrayInicial[@]}")`:

```
$ arrayRanks=({a..c} ${arrayRanks[@]})
$ printf "%s\n" "${arrayRanks[@]}" 
a
b
c
a
b
c
A
B
...
```

Comment: naa tio eres un pvto genio, siempre tienes las respuestas para bash xd.